# Release Variable assigned a value from file rather than in TFS

Tags: tfs

In the release config, under the Variables tab, I am wondering if it is possible to make the Value point to a file.

I want to do this because we are using the release to run parallel UI tests. Currently, we take the tests and split them out into different chunks which we then define in TFS as Group_A, Group_B, etc..

What we are doing now, is creating a build folder inside the solution that whenever the solution is built, it creates a .txt file of all the namespaces in the test directory. I am trying to use this .txt file as the value of the TestGroup variable in the release. Is this possible?

Comment: Your proposed approach is probably not a good approach. What test framework are you using? Depending on your test framework, there's almost certainly a native method of categorizing and selectively running tests. The Visual Studio Test task even has the ability to parallelize tests automatically.

Comment: @DanielMann Our testing framework is a bit unique.. These are not web tests, this is automation for a Windows app. We use LeanFT as the testing framework and NUnit as the test runner. LeanFT does not support parallel testing out of the box so this is our approach. Has worked well with sharding the different tests into groups but now we would rather pass out each test class as the multipler for the release

Comment: @DanielMann to add to that, we use NUnit and include the Category tab to shard our tests, [Category("Group_A")]. We do not want to do this because its hard to maintain after a period of time, therefore we just want to get all the test classes and run those

Comment: @Tree55Topz You can try writing a PowerShell script to read the contents from the `.txt` file and set variables by the [logging command](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) : `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=variablename] split-value"`, then run the script in release process.

Comment: @Tree55Topz Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT thanks for checking in - moved on to some other more important things but we are still looking to implement this in the next few weeks. After talking with other developers they were recommending the same thing. Will update this thread with our solution once it is implemented